# UI-Grid sorting is not working on column if values is in format (60%, 30%, 20% etc)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs UI-Grid library for grid and set default sorter enable.
e.g. enableSorting=true, But its not working on few column where column format is in number and percentage sign (10,0%.90% etc).
Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have formatting a "filter" on a column, and it affects how your sorting should occur, you'll want to add to the column definitions:

`sortCellFiltered: true`

> (optional) False by default. When true uiGrid will apply the cellFilter before sorting the data. Note that when using this option uiGrid will assume that the displayed value is a string, and use the sortAlpha sortFn. It is possible to return a non-string value from an angularjs filter, in which case you should define a sortingAlgorithm for the column which hanldes the returned type. You may specify one of the sortingAlgorithms found in the rowSorter service.

Also of interest for filtering may be:

`filterCellFiltered: true`.

> (optional) False by default. When true uiGrid will apply the cellFilter before applying "search" filters.

Reference:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef

Answer (score 0):

Try `sortDirectionCycle` to remove the third state of sorting.

```
columnDefs: [
{ field: 'name', sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, 
uiGridConstants.DESC] },
{ field: 'gender', sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, 
uiGridConstants.DESC] },
{ field: 'company', enableSorting: false }
]
```

From document, When clicking on a column heading the sort direction will cycle to ascending, then descending, then back to unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution, In my scenario, I got object values in string format like [{persent: "10%"},{percent: "0%"}, {percent: "90%"}]; So i have provide type in column definition eg. type: 'numberStr'. and its working for me.